# Kusto - How to find which operation/exception caused 524/5xx error in Azure Application Insight?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

i'm noob to Kusto, can anyone share how to get the operation/exception that caused failed request (5xx http) in Azure Application Insight log with starttime & endtime provided ?

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure portal Application Insights navigate to logs tab and add the below query (In your case resultCode is 5XX)

```
requests
| where resultCode == 404
| summarize Count=sum(itemCount) by url
| sort by Count
```

Below is screenshot from the portal:
[image]

Also refer to this [swinburger blog](https://swimburger.net/blog/azure/querying-404s-using-kusto-and-log-analytics-in-azure-application-insights), and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532755/how-to-query-my-application-insights-logs-analytics-from-kusto-explorer) thread.

Comment: Thanks @Saikarri, but what i'm looking for is the operation/exception which caused the failed http code (5xx), not the url

Comment: Hello @MikeNg, The mentioned steps are general procedure for querying the data in Application Insights. Check this [blog](https://mishrasmrutiranjan.blog/2019/05/31/querying-data-from-multiple-application-insights/) and [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/app-insights-metrics) to customize queries according to your requirement